# Whether or not to use multiple instances of an Activity on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-navigation

If I have an app that refills a ListView with different data in response to a user selecting an item.  Should I start a new Activity or just change the data, and call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

It seems like calling notifyDataSetChanged() is simpler, and would minimize my potential number of activities (and memory usage), but I want the Up/Back navigation to work.

My app works like File Explorer where there is a list of folders, and clicking on a folder changes the list to show the contents of the new folder.  If the user clicks on a folder, I want the Up/Back buttons to take them back to the prior folder.  I have implemented this with a single instance of the activity and using notifyDataSetChanged(), but can't get the Up/Back buttons working as desired.  I am thinking I need to either override those somehow, or use multiple instances of the same activity.  Any direction here would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you needs multiple view pages in single Activity, you can tried out `fragments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple instances of the same Activity is highly unproductive.

To solve your problem, the best way to do it would be to use a fragment using multiple instances of it, each one representing a folder in your arborescence. Then in the `onBackPressed()` of your activity, you can just 
use [popBackStack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()) while there is a fragment in the backStack, then call `super.onBackPressed()` to resume default behavior.

---

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I will try this out.